# waitForAngularEnable(true) NOT working - ScriptTimeoutError: script timeout: result was not received in

Tags: angular, typescript, protractor, cucumber

Starting page angular. By clicking a button will lead to the login page which is None-angular. After login rest of the pages are angular.

I'm using *async/await*.

- Include `waitForAngularEnable`(*true*) in onPrepare but didn't work.
- Try adding `waitForAngularEnable`(*true*) after login and this didn't
  work.
- Tried with increasing the `timeOut` and that didn't work too.
- Works only when `waitForAngularEnable`(*false*). I can't use the inbuilt feature in protractor waiForAngular which wait until angular to load. Currently with waitForAngularEnable(false) I'm manually handling it using browser.driver.wait(until.elementsLocated(by.id(value)), 30000); or await browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.presenceOf(ele), 30000);. This way it works.

> Versions-
>  "protractor": "^5.4.2"
>  "node" : 10.15.3
>   "target": "es6" 
>  "cucumber": "^5.1.0",
>   "cucumber-html-reporter": "^5.0.0"
>  ScriptTimeoutError: script
>   timeout: result was not received in 30 seconds
>            (Session info: chrome=74.0.3729.169)
>            (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 
> (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Windows
>   NT 10.0.17763 x86_64)
>              at Object.checkLegacyResponse 
> (C:\Automation\General\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:546:15)
>              at parseHttpResponse (C:\Automation\General\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:509:13)
>              at doSend.then.response (C:\Automation\General\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:441:30)
>              at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
>          From: Task: Protractor.waitForAngular() - Locator: By(xpath, //span[@class='title__subtext'])

Comment: If it works then what is your problem. You will have to set waitForAngularEnable(false) for Non-Angular pages.

Comment: I can't use the inbuilt feature in protractor waiForAngular which wait until angular to load. Currently with waitForAngularEnable(false) I'm manually handling it using browser.driver.wait(until.elementsLocated(by.id(value)), 30000); or await browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.presenceOf(ele), 30000);. This way it works.

Answer (score 0):

**What you are doing (per my understanding of your problem)**

- open angular page
- login
- you're redirected to non-angular page (at this point protractor already not responding)
- you try `await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);` (but protractor doesn't respond because you're on non-angular page)

**What you should be doing**

- open angular page
- enter credentials
- before you click submit button run `await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);`
- you're redirected to non-angular page (at this point protractor can communicate with it)
- do whatever you want to do

Simply, you have to disable waiting for angular WHILE you're still on angular page

P.S. and vice versa. if you're navigating from non-angular page back to angular, you must enable the feature only when you landed on angular page

Answer (score 0):

Using `waitForAngularEnabled` multiple times in the same test can be done, but requires a non-obvious addition of `browser.get`. You can use the following:

```
// do things on your Angular application

waitForAngularEnabled(false)

// do things on non-angular page

waitForAngularEnabled(true)
browser.get('/home') // this is a page from your Angular application
```

The `browser.get` function blocks until the Angular page is loaded.

Answer (score -1):

For Angular apps, Protractor will wait until the `Angular Zone` stabilizes. This means long-running async operations will block your test from continuing. To work around this, run the following tasks outside of the Angular Zone.

Probably you need to set this timeout as a patch until the issue is fixed in application level

```
allScriptsTimeout: 60000
```

Found a good article on this:
https://valor-software.com/articles/testing-with-protractor-how-to-fix-synchronization-issues.html